# PHP MYSQLI query error?

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

Hey This is my login script, using PHP5 and MYSQLi, I just had help spotting errors in my query, but still it will not let me login, even though the username and password are correct and in the database, it just keeps returning the error: your username and password do not match any in our db. But I know they do lol...could any body spot the problem?

```
//Check if the form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
    {   
        //Check if username and password are empty
        if ($_POST['username']!='' && $_POST['password']!='') 
        {       
            //Create query to check username and password to database
            $validate_user = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, username, password, active FROM users WHERE = username = "'.$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']).'" AND password = "'.$mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])).'"');

            //We check if the query returns true
            if ($validate_user->num_rows == 1)
            {
                $row = $validate_user->fetch_assoc();

                //Check if the user has activated there account
                if ($row['activated'] == 1)
                {
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                    Header('Location: ../main/index.php');
                }
                //Show this error if activation returns as 0
                else {
                    $error = '<p class="error">Please activate your account.</p>';
                }
            }
                //Show this error if the details matched any in the db
                else {      
                    $error = '<p class="error">Your username and password are not in our database!</p>';        
                }
            }
                //Show this error if the username and password field have not been entered
                else {
                    $error = '<p class="error">Please enter your username and password.</p>';
                }
    }
```

Comment: do you have an md5 hash in the password field?

Comment: Yes, would you like me to show you?

Comment: Do you have more than one user with this username/password combination?

Comment: Nope, I am the only user in the database as I am developing atm :(

Comment: you don't check query execution for errors. add this code echo $mysqli->error; to see if there was any

Comment: Not related to your problem, but don't use md5 to store passwords. Use crypt with the blowfish algorithm.

Comment: Col. Thank you, that showed me that god damn "active" was not the correct name of my field, it was activated. idiot. thank you, a good one to remember that thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it most reliable way, I'd suggest to trigger this error according to main error handling settings:

```
//just in sake of readability
$user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));

$sql = "SELECT id, username, password, active FROM users 
        WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";

$res = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error(mysqli->error.$sql);
```

note that `trigger_error` function. it will bring error message to the standard error output. On the development PC it will be browser's screen or a log file on the production server.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

SELECT ... FROM users WHERE = username = ...

It should be

SELECT ... FROM users WHERE username = ...

If you keep getting problems like this, try storing the query in a variable and echo it, so you can copy-paste it into your database management tool and see if there are any query errors.

Comment: Thanks it as just a simple mis type of a db field :(